# How to set the width and height of igxDialog?

Tags: angular, infragistics, ignite-ui, ignite-ui-angular

I am trying to create a modal Dialog, but the width is not applied correctly.

```html
<igx-dialog
  #alert
  title="Notification"
  message="Your email has been sent successfully!"
  leftButtonLabel="OK"
  (onLeftButtonSelect)="alert.close()"
  style="width:1000px"
></igx-dialog>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can position the `IgxDialogComponent` in a custom div and then apply the desired styles. For this purpose you should use the `IgxOverlayService` of the `IgxToggleDirective` which the `IgxDialogComponent` uses.

A sample where this can be seen can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-igxdialog-size?file=src/app/dialog-sample-1/dialog-sample-1.component.html)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/dialog#position-and-animation-settings) there is a `[positionSettings]` where you can customize the property `minSize`. This will allow you to create a custom `width` and `height` for the dialog but this only works for what they call [Elastic Positioning Strategy](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/overlay-position#elastic).

From what I have seen there is no property to which you can bind a change in `width` or `height`. It also seems not possible to pass down a style by input property.

Please check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qz3pbr?file=src/app/dialog/dialog-styling-sample/dialog-styling-sample.component.scss) an example that I have altered to change the width of the dialog by styling the CSS. The base code was taken from an example from the documentation but I thought it could be useful since it's an example on how you can create a custom style for the component. I simply added the `width` to the styling for testing and I believe it achieves your goal